# Определение типов для СВОЕЙ библиотеки в d.ts файле

Tags: typescript

Так и не нашел работающего примера, где можно определять свои собственные типы в файле `d.ts`. Часто задают вопросы про определение типов для уже существующих библиотек, но что насчёт своих собственных?

Из [шаблона от Майкрософта](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html) я понял, что файл следует назвать `index.d.ts` и положить его в корень проекта. Приведу полный код шаблона для тех, кому лень открывать ссылку:

```
// Type definitions for [~THE LIBRARY NAME~] [~OPTIONAL VERSION NUMBER~]
// Project: [~THE PROJECT NAME~]
// Definitions by: [~YOUR NAME~] <[~A URL FOR YOU~]>

/*~ This is the module template file. You should rename it to index.d.ts
 *~ and place it in a folder with the same name as the module.
 *~ For example, if you were writing a file for "super-greeter", this
 *~ file should be 'super-greeter/index.d.ts'
 */

/*~ If this module is a UMD module that exposes a global variable 'myLib' when
 *~ loaded outside a module loader environment, declare that global here.
 *~ Otherwise, delete this declaration.
 */
export as namespace myLib;

/*~ If this module has methods, declare them as functions like so.
 */
export function myMethod(a: string): string;
export function myOtherMethod(a: number): number;

/*~ You can declare types that are available via importing the module */
export interface someType {
    name: string;
    length: number;
    extras?: string[];
}

/*~ You can declare properties of the module using const, let, or var */
export const myField: number;

/*~ If there are types, properties, or methods inside dotted names
 *~ of the module, declare them inside a 'namespace'.
 */
export namespace subProp {
    /*~ For example, given this definition, someone could write:
     *~   import { subProp } from 'yourModule';
     *~   subProp.foo();
     *~ or
     *~   import * as yourMod from 'yourModule';
     *~   yourMod.subProp.foo();
     */
    export function foo(): void;
}
```

Из этого шаблона непонятно два момента:

1. В шаблоне уйма export-ов. Нужно что, каждый тип отдельно импортировать в файл, где он используется?! Нет, так быть не должно: типы для всех популярных библиотек типа `JQuery` доступны для использовании без импорта в явном виде. Стало быть, export-ы лишние?
2. Как бы то не было, если просто добавить этот шаблон, типы в файле с основным кодом видны не будут. Как добиться того, чтобы и внутри проекта, и в проектах, где код используется, типы были видны?

Для этого примера я подготовил просто класс. В результате правильного обеспечения видимости файла `.d.ts` данный класс должен понимать типы `modes` и `LayoutParameters`:

```
class TestClass {

    mode: modes;
    layoutParameters: LayoutParameters;

    constructor(mode: modes, layoutParameters: LayoutParameters) {
        this.mode = mode;
        this.layoutParameters: layoutParameters;
    }
}
```

### index.d.ts

```
enum modes {DEVELOPMENT, PRODUCTION};

type LayoutParameters = {
    widths: {
        min: number,
        max: number
    },
    zIndexes: {
        modalsOverlay: number,
        modals: number 
    }
}
```

Comment: не нужно их нигде импортировать, typescript на этапе компиляции рекурсивно делает `include` всех `.d.ts` файлов в директории с `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Благодарю Вас за комментарий! А как следует тогда объявлять типы? Через `declare`? `type`?

Comment: если вы делаете свою библиотеку, то вам не нужны объявления на этапе разработки, они генерятся компилятором если установлен флаг `declaration` когда билдится сама либа для паблишинга на npm например, то же вы можете увидеть в `@types/jquery` с кучей экспортов, это не люди вручную пишут, это дело рук компилятора, вы просто создаете файл `types.ts` и там объявляете свои типы, и импортируете их там где нужно

Comment: @overthesanity Благодарю Вас за объяснение! К сожалению, я не понял начиная с `вы просто создаете файл`. Хотя без установки `@types/jquery` типизация JQuery действительно не работает, я не помню, чтобы что-то в явном виде импортировал из `@types/jquery`. Если я правильно понял Ваш первый комментарий, то файл в `@types/jquery` был включен автоматически TypeScrip-ом. Это так?

Comment: вы делаете библиотеку, в руте директории `tsconfig.json | webpack.config.ts | node_modules | src` (как пример), в папке `src` у вас файл `types.ts` с типами, которые нужны вашей либе и импортируются в других файлах `import { LayoutParameters } from './types'` и да, компилятор сам инклудит все декларайшены в любой папке где лежит `tsconfig.json`, что-то типа `glob(join(__dirname, './**/*.d.ts'))`, под капотом реализация конечно сложнее

Comment: @overthesanity Хорошо, понял. Следующий непонятный момент: если задать опцию ` "declaration": true` и в `index.ts` создать класс, то в скомпилированном `index.d.ts` будет `declare class ExampleClass` и далее всё как объявление интерфейса. Вопрос: а необходимость в этом `declare class ExampleClass` есть? Если импортировать этот класс себе в проект, то `TypeScript` и так будет видеть, какие свойства и методы у `ExampleClass`.

Comment: нет, вы же будете импортировать потом не с `.ts` файла, а с `.js`, поэтому `.d.ts` - это так сказать метаданные для компилятора, когда вы будет паблишить на npm либу, то вы же не будете паблишить `.ts` файлы, вы будете паблишить `.js + .d.ts`

Comment: @overthesanity, я правильно Вас понял, что `d.ts` нужен именно для таких случаев? (когда импортируем `.js` в `ts`-проект и TypeScript-у как-то нужно понимать, какие типы используется). А так, в большинстве случаев импорт именно из `.ts`, поскольку и webpack имеет `ts-loader`, и для nodejs есть `ts-node`.

Comment: конечно, объявления `.d.ts` нужны только при работе с js либой, то есть когда когда вы делаете свою либу с `.ts.` файлами, то от `.d.ts` как бы нет проку, потому что `.ts` файлы типизированы

Comment: @overthesanity, Благодарю Вас за объяснения. Как же тогда следует быть в случаях, когда нам нужно определить свои типы для использования как внутри своей библиотеки, так и вне её? В примере из вопроса это  `enum modes {DEVELOPMENT, PRODUCTION};`. К сожалению, это перечисление нельзя сделать статическим свойством класса, а определять его вне класса в том же файле я не хочу (пусть будет 1 файл - 1 класс). Если же определить её в index.d.ts и задать опцию declaration, то, естественно, перечисление `modes` будет стёрто. Следует создать ещё один файл `.d.ts`?

Comment: следует создать любой `.ts`, объявить там это перечисление и импортировать там где нужно :)

Comment: @overthesanity, Понял! Думаю, на этом данный вопрос исчерпан. Благодарю Вас за ответы, или, вернее сказать, консультацию!

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, определитесь на каком языке вы пишите библиотеку: на Javascript или на Typescript.

Если ваша библиотека написана на Javascript - то ваш файл с типами должен называться не `index.d.ts`, а так же как ваш `.js`-файл, только с расширением `.d.ts`.

Если ваша библиотека написана на Typescript - то вам **не нужен** отдельный файл с объявлениями типов. Вам нужно объявлять типы в основном файле.

---

Что же до экспортов - вы несколько отстали от современных технологий. Лезущая в глобальное пространство имён JQuery - это как раз пример *ненормальной* библиотеки! Правильная библиотека в мире ECMAScript, начиная с 2015й версии, должна объявлять набор экспортов. Да, их потом нужно будет отдельно импортировать - но это, вообще-то, проще чем объяснять компилятору и IDE откуда вы взяли глобальную переменную `$`.

Comment: внимательно прочитал Ваш ответ. Прежде всего благодарю Вас за него. Исходный код библиотеки у меня на TypeScript и я хотел бы вообще обойтись без компиляции в JS (webpack и так подвяжет .ts-модули библиотеки). Но из-за того, что при сборке кода Webpack-ом для Node.js зависимости привязывать к сборке не рекомендуется (используется `webpack-node-externals`), откомпилированный и запущенный Node.js-ом JavaScript просто не сможет импортировать .ts-модуль, компиляцию в JS пришлось обеспечить. Вы бы не могли дать ссылку на пример, как объявить типы в основном файле?

Comment: @БоковГлеб пример чего? Ну вот например: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

Comment: @ PavelMayorov, пример "объявления типов в основном файле" и "Правильной библиотеки с набором экспортов".

Comment: @БоковГлеб так я и привёл пример объявления перечисления в файле с кодом. Что вам там непонятно?

Comment: @БоковГлеб примеры же нормальных библиотек - React, Angular, Mobx, rx.js, стандартная библиотека Nodejs...

Comment: не понял, какое отношения имеют перечисления enum к вопросу, но определения типов к тем библиотекам, которые Вы привели в качестве примера, я посмотрю.

Comment: @БоковГлеб как какое отношение? Вы попросили пример объявления типа в основном файле, я его привёл.

Comment: ладно, я думаю, этот вопрос слишком широкий по масштабу, поэтому в этом вопросе мы обсуждение закончим, я приму Вас ответ, а сам задам ещё несколько более конкретных вопросов.