# Можно ли в TypeScript экспортировать/импртировать одноимённые имя класса и пространство имён одновременно?

Tags: typescript

Есть класс (допустим, `ExampleUtil`), находящийся в одноимённом файле `ExampleUtil.ts`. На данный момент типы, с которыми работает этот класс, хранятся в файле `ExampleUtil__TYPES.ts`, и при импорте их в `ExampleUtil.ts` проблем не возникает. На данном этапе нужды в пространствах имён нет.

Когда пришла пора использовать `ExampleUtil` в других проектах, то оказалось, что типы из `ExampleUtil__TYPES.ts` имеют контекстно-зависящие имена и их было бы неплохо инкапсулировать в пространство имён. Но имя `ExampleUtil` уже занято классом, а потому нужно либо выбрать другое имя для пространства имён, либо как-то разрешить этот конфликт имён.

Следуя рекомендациям к ответу на вопрос [Определение типов для СВОЕЙ библиотеки в d.ts файле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1015721/193415), я организовал определения типов к своей библиотеке `my-lib.d.ts` таким образом:

```
import ExampleUtil from "./ExampleUtil/ExampleUtil";
import { Type1, Type2 } from "./ExampleUtil/ExampleUtil__TYPES"
import OtherUtil from "./OtherUtil/OtherUtil";
import { Type3, Type4 } from "./OtherUtil/OtherUtil__TYPES"
// другие функции и класссы библиотеки


/** Ре-экспорт всех зависимостей для других проектов.
 *  В отличие от "lodash", где каждая функция находится в одном файле, 
 *  при этом все в одной директории, такой подход позволяет разработчикам 
 *  организовывать файлы по подпапкам, при этом пользователи могут 
 *  использовать всё, что им надо из единственного файла "my-lib", например
 *  import { ExampleUtil, Type1, Type2 } from "my-lib";
 *  Все возможности данной библиотеки, которые не используются, будут удалены 
 *  из JavaScript-бандла оптимизацией Webpack-а.
 */
export {
  ExampleUtil, Type1, Type2,
  OtherUtil, Type3, Type4,
  // ... другие функции и классы
};
```

Если мы обернём `Type1` и `Type2` в пространство имён `ExampleUtil`, то конфликт возникнет уже на этом этапе: мы импортируем и класс и одноимённое пространство имён, а потом и то и другое ещё нужно как-то ре-экпортировать.

Итак, есть ли способ писать код наподобие:

```
//                                Пространство имён
const parameterForExampleUtil: ExampleUtil.Type1 = { /* ... */ };
//             Пространство имён     Класс
const result: ExampleUtil.Type2 = ExampleUtil.getSomething(parameterForExampleUtil);
```

и если нет, то какую схему именования пространств имён Вы можете предложить? Может, есть какие-то схемы именования в других языках? Есть же, например, схема именования интерфейсов `I<Имя соответствующего класса>`, так может и для пространств имён что-то аналогичное есть?

Comment: нет, зачем смешивать типы и значения?

Comment: ExampleUtil - будет пространство имен, а класс назовите как-то по другому и обращайтесь через то же пространство имен

Comment: @ThisMan, да я не исключаю, что незачем.

Comment: @ThisMan То есть получится что-то вроде `new ExampleUtil.OtherNameClass()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можно ли в TypeScript экспортировать/импртировать одноимённые имя класса и пространство имён одновременно?

да, можно.

[там песочница](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?noImplicitAny=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&alwaysStrict=false&esModuleInterop=false#code/LYewJgrgNgpgBARwO4EM4G84HouNQOgBcBnAKDgu1wAtDCAHALhyVaIE96ZiBjAJwCW9QlBQA7AOb4QfCVjAgexLNXFgARiBABreTB6i+KQgJBiAtMBiyBk-LWBQAxFZuTzYlFeL0UPbuSUMAAe9DKEcAYoxMRwABJ8MABmGIGUlBB8UIxwxISCkgDcaelwKFCEOXkFEsWllJ5WVfm2tSXpPGbVEDyEMgAUmOURALxwAOTEIFZwYMn4s9w8+OMANHD4m-R8IPSxAL45CfMAJNu7xACUqfX1APLqAFb6hPjRxAISYv2E1ALE6yGFXWm3w5z2cH2l3alH2JTh6RCYT4EUa3F8-niiRS6BhFBwcAAAiRzJ8xDIYHi4EjwnBbIRrEk-PAzjsISEGWIwLFjjiqelhgB+Zo1Oq3BGwkoEtE+ZlY5IYSGlAkAUQASmqcgBJLkCABuAkg5UWUSMJi6dLEcFcEhgYBNhmMpit41542tEDycHU8HKUGpoXCdrgMjKUH9UEU5XwJRpKLgMox8F5iv2VDphAABrEdHApbhzKtzKQ4aBILBLXNgoqCbYq0QyB0uhEU2NkCh8Cna8BkRFMCm00kdsAJu3xvm4IXi02xF6oLZtABGOBjMQwJDypKDBNeGA5cZrOCZbITQ-DffuqElTqziLzsTaABMK4T68327RF-Wx4vkOhE9oBhmCwVgkA4LheEEYRRDsGQ5AUJQVDUTQdCwCATHnQh2HMLCIPsQhHCcWw8nEfxcJgQgSnIuATmobEXx1EixH8AAVTgYAAHnIkAUl5AA+a9mzgOjkhyWj6LGXFbh3JpT1WKkfzkqlzyU9I4ThIA)

### merging-namespaces

- http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-namespaces
  там, официальная документация

```
module qwa { // qwa.ts
    export class Href {
        url: string;
        alt: string;
        name: string;
        constructor({ alt = 'some def. desc.', ...props }: Href.$props) {
            Object.assign(this, { alt, ...props })
        }
    }
    export namespace Href {
        // @ts-ignore
        export interface $props extends Href {
            alt?: string;
        }
    }
    // namespace Href { }     // ERR: Individual declarations in merged declaration 'Href' must be all exported or all local.
    export namespace Href { } // it`s ok 
}
module index { // index.ts
    const Href = qwa.Href // import { Href } from 'qwa'
    // -,-
    const link1 = new Href({ name: '', url: '', alt: '' })
    const link2 = new Href({ name: '', url: '' })
}
```

### и ещё, как преобразовать класс в тип?

- `InstanceType<T>` http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypet

```
class C {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

type T0 = InstanceType<typeof C>;
```

### ах, да!

```
class C1 { }
namespace C1 {
    export const VARIABLE = 'VARIABLE'
}
```

аналогично

```
class C2 {
    static VARIABLE = 'VARIABLE'
}
```

с тем лишь различием, что в пространстве имён можно объявить и экспортировать типы и интерфейсы

```
class C2 {
    static VARIABLE = 'VARIABLE'
    type $props = { q: string } // ERR
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за подробный ответ!